# Environment variables in README

Tags: github

I'm going to push my code to GitHub. I've placed .env files in .gitignore since I have some passwords there. What would be the best way to guide other users how to create environment variables? Is it ok if I mention in README that .env file should be created with appropriate variables? Is there a better way of handling this problem?

Comment: Yes, you can put it in the README. You can also include an e.g. `.env.example` to show the right structure/variables.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's perfectly fine to mention in the README that users should create a `.env` file with appropriate variables. This is a common practice in projects where sensitive information like passwords or API keys are stored in environment variables. Additionally, you can provide instructions in the README on how to set up these environment variables, including the expected format and any specific variables that need to be defined.

Another approach to handling this problem is to provide a template `.env.example` file in your repository that users can copy and rename to `.env`, filling in the appropriate values for their environment. This can serve as a helpful starting point for users and ensures they don't accidentally overlook any required variables.

The goal is to provide clear guidance to users on how to set up their environment variables while also ensuring the security of sensitive information.